# Problema com SSL no plugin Cielo Webservice Woocommerce

Tags: api, woocommerce, ssl, tls

Ao tentar salvar as configurações no WooCommerce (colocando Chave de afiliação e Número de afiliação) aparece uma mensagem dizendo:

**“Cielo WooCommerce desabilitado: Um certificado SSL é necessário para utilizar a Solução Webservice. Por favor, verifique se um certificado esta instalado no seu servidor”.**

A principio imaginei que poderia ser um problema do meu certificado SSL ou versão do TLS (tem tópicos aqui no suporte sobre isso). Mas mesmo testando todas as opções e verificações (meu certificado e TLS estão ok como pode ser visto no link https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.correcotiakids.com.br).
Nos logs também não tem nada a respeito.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Eu abri um tópico na página oficial do plugin, mas sem sucesso até agora.
As soluções presentes no link https://wordpress.org/support/topic/solucao-para-quem-esta-com-problemas-do-tls/ não funcionaram. Até por que como citei acima, já testei o SSL e o TLS e estão ok.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, eu estava com esse problema então entrei no (seudominio.com/)wp-admin/options.php e alterei a função "woocommerce_force_ssl_checkout" de "no" para "yes"